# list and recursion in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I dealt with a problem during a test, but I do not understand why my answer does not work.
According to the statement one gives two numbers for each number the number which follows it is the same number plus the sum of the digits of this number. For this purpose, although the two sequences are with different starting points, they can end up joining. And I'm being asked to find the juncture.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So this is my source code:

```
def compute_join_point(s_1, s_2):
    v_1 = s_1 + sum([int(i) for i in str(s_1)])
    v_2 = s_2 + sum([int(i) for i in str(s_2)])
    if v_1 == v_2:
        return v_1
    else:
        compute_join_point(v_1, v_2)
```

execution

```
s_1 = [471, 483, 498]
s_2 = [480, 492, 507]
rslt = 0
for i in s_1:
   for j in s_2: 
       rslt = compute_join_point(i, j)
print(rslt)
```

but I don't know how to resolve this problem
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYuh0.png

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you get an error or just not the expected result? BTW, why do you use the lists ```s_1``` and ```s_2```? Shouldn't the integers 471 and 480 be sufficient to get the desired result, at least for testing purposes?

Comment: Hey, exactly. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem I see in your code is that you are missing a `return` keyword to propagate your result when the function collapses:

```
def compute_join_point(s_1, s_2):
    v_1 = s_1 + sum([int(i) for i in str(s_1)])
    v_2 = s_2 + sum([int(i) for i in str(s_2)])
    if v_1 == v_2:
        return v_1
    else:
        return compute_join_point(v_1, v_2)
```